# How to set other elements to hide when body element is set to full screen using react?

Tags: reactjs

i want to hide some elements within body element when body element is set to full screen.

What i am trying to do?

within index.html file i have

```
 <html>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <div id="modal"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Within main application component i have

```
return (
    <First/>
    <TopComponent/>
    <Switch>
        <Route>
            <div>
                <div style={{display: 'flex'}>
                    <NavBar/>
                    <div className="content">
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" render= 
                            {this.render_items}/>
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
    </Switch>
);
```

And in itemspage component when i click on fullscrenbtn it sets the body element to fullscreen.

```
extend default class ItemsPage extends React.Purecomponent (
    open_full_screen = () => {
        let elem = document.findElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
            elem.requestFullscreen();
        }
    }
    render = () => {
        return (
            <button onclick= 
                {this.open_full_screen}>fullscreenbtn</button>
        ) 
    }
}
```

Now as you notice from above itemspage component it sets the entire elements in body tag on full screen.

Now the question is i don't want certain elements not to be displayed in fullscreen like the components before the content div

```
<First/>
    <TopComponent/>
    <Switch>
        <Route>
            <div>
                <div style={{display: 'flex'}>
                    <NavBar/>
```

How can i do that. could someone help me with it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the visibility value of those components in state. For example you state may look like below

```
components :{
        First : "visible",
        "Switch" : "hidden"
      }
```

And your react JSX may look this :

```
<First style :`Visibility : ${this.state.component.First}`/>
    <TopComponent/>
    <Switch `Visibility : ${this.state.component.First}`>
```